# Como imprimir un string en un textview letra por letra en java?

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero imprimir un string que recorro con un bucle for pero no se como dar una pausa y volver a recorrer el bucle conservando lo que ya hay escrito, quiero dar el efecto como si el mensaje se estuviera escribiendo en el momento, lo he intentado con el siguiente código pero espera el tiempo total y lo imprime de golpe. Saludos y gracias!

```
    private void bucle() {
        String saludo = "Hola chavales";
        int pausa = 100;

        for (int i = 1; i <= saludo.length(); i++) {
            try {
            tpantalla.setText(modelSplash.toString().substring(0, i));
                Thread.sleep(pausa);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que esta es la respuesta que buscas -> [Ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y funciona genial!!

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, en realidad lo importante aquí es el uso de un Handler para cambiar cada n segundos el texto en el TextView, @Alex saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usando un `Handler` para escribir cada letra de la cadena en un tiempo definido, en este caso como ejemplo medio segundo (500 ms):

```
    final long DELAY = 500;
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        //Write every letter in CharSequence
                        textView.setText(myPoem.subSequence(0, counter));
                        counter++;

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, DELAY);  //DELAY every n milliseconds
```

Otra opción es si prefieres usar un `TextView` personalizado,

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class TypeWriter extends AppCompatTextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private CharSequence mOriginalText;
    private long delay = 1000; // 1 second
    private int mIndex;

    public TypeWriter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if(mIndex <= mText.length()) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, delay);
            }else{
                mIndex = 0;
                mText = mOriginalText;
                setText("");
            }
        }
    };

    public void animateText(CharSequence text) {
        setText("");
        mText = text;
        mOriginalText = text;
        mIndex = 0;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, delay);
    }

    //*Overrides delay value, default is 1 second.
    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis) {
        delay = millis;
    }
}
```

para esto en el layout cambiarías la definición del `TextView` de

```
<TextView
```

a

```
 <[Paquete de aplicación].TypeWriter
```

Con ambas opciones puedes crear algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `TextView` personalizado es lo que se realiza en libraries como [TypeWriter](https://github.com/skymansandy/typewriterview)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la siguiente libreria tambien

https://github.com/skymansandy/typewriterview

Entre sus configuraciones puedes modificar el tiempo, el "sonido" (como maquina de escribir) mas cualquier atributo de un textview normal.

```
<in.codeshuffle.typewriterview.TypeWriterView
   android:id="@+id/typeWriterView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textStyle="bold" />     

TypeWriterView typeWriterView=(TypeWriterView)findViewById(R.id.typeWriterView);
typeWriterView.setDelay(int);
typeWriterView.setWithMusic(boolean);
typeWriterView.animateText(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para los que necesitan este código así como yo lo necesite, como mostrar o imprimir lo que vas escribiendo letra a letra:

---

1.-Primero instanciamos en donde vamos a escribir:

```
Nombre=(EditText)Dialogo.findViewById ( R.id.etNombreDialog );
```

2.- Luego usamos el `TextChangedListener`, que nos ayudara a mostrar, antes, durante y después que hayamos ingresado el texto:

```
 Nombre.addTextChangedListener ( new TextWatcher () {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                if(Nombre.getText().length() >= 0) {
                    System.out.println(" IMPRESIONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN!!!!!!!!!!!! " +  Nombre.getText().toString());

                }

            }
        } );
```

Answer (score -1):

Una de las formas de hacerlo es con un hilo dentro del bucle for, en donde el hilo con el metodo .sleep, de la clase Thread permite darle el tiempo que quiere que se demore haciendo la accion, en este caso iterando el en el bucle, el tiempo que recibe el metodo .sleep() esta dado en milisegundos, entonces si quiere que dure un segundo, le coloca 1000 milisegundos acá dejo el codigo de como se haría

```
package views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainWindow extends JDialog{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel lbText;

    public MainWindow() {
        lbText = new JLabel();
        setSize(400, 500);

        add(lbText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= text.length(); i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                lbText.setText(text.substring(0, i));
                repaint();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.setText(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el texto"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Debe ser con Android Studio y java no Javax